# Django-admin вывести список городов из связанной модели

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

Хочу чтобы вместо вот этого

[image: как есть]

Был нормальный выбор города

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Следующий код выводит на форму Django-admin нужный мне выбор, но не может сохранить результат выбора в базу, так как на вход нужен объект City, а не Int (city.pk)

```
class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField('Город', max_length=40, unique=True)


class Contact(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Город',
                             choices=[(obj.pk, obj.city,) for obj in City.objects.all()])
    street = models.CharField('Улица', max_length=200, default='')
    postcode = models.CharField('Почтовый индекс', max_length=6, default='')
    mobile = models.CharField('Телефон', max_length=200, default='')
```

Тоже не правильно:

```
choices=[(obj, obj.city,) for obj in City.objects.all()]
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__str__

Comment: @gisolog Спасибо!

Comment: Вот интересно о чем ссылка и за что спасибо?

Comment: @Wertartem Добавил ответ, Спасибо было за ссылку в которой моя проблема решена с помощью метода __ str __

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было добавить метод `__str__`

```
class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField('Город', max_length=40, unique=True)
    ctime = models.DateTimeField('Запись создана', default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city
```